# Rare inequality of measurements $4|\mu(A\cup B)\mu(A\cap B)-\mu(A)\mu(B)|\leq\mu^{2}(A\cup B)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}$ of $X$, and let $A,B\in\mathcal{T}$

Show that $4|\mu(A\cup B)\mu(A\cap B)-\mu(A)\mu(B)|\leq\mu^{2}(A\cup B)$.

I tried to prove it by contradiction, assuming that the measure of each set is finite:

\begin{align*}
& &2\mu(A\cup B)\mu(A\cap B)-2\mu(A)\mu(B)&>\frac{1}{2}\mu^{2}(A\cup B)\\
\Rightarrow& &\mu^{2}(A\cup B)+2\mu(A\cup B)\mu(A\cap B)+\mu^{2}(A\cap B)-2\mu(A)\mu(B)&>\frac{3}{2}\mu^{2}(A\cup B)+\mu^{2}(A\cap B)\\
\Leftrightarrow& &\mu^{2}(A)+2\mu(A)\mu(B)+\mu^{2}(B)-2\mu(A)\mu(B)&>\frac{3}{2}\mu^{2}(A\cup B)+\mu^{2}(A\cap B)\\
\Rightarrow& &\mu^{2}(A)+\mu^{2}(B)&>\frac{3}{2}\mu^{2}(A\cup B)+\mu^{2}(A\cap B)\\
\end{align*}
Now I don't know how to continue, I don't even know if I'm on the right track, in fact I'm beginning to believe that the exercise contains some error. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=\mu(A\setminus B)$, $b=\mu(B\setminus A)$ and $c=\mu(A\cap B)$, with $a,b,c\ge 0$. The inequality you are being asked to prove is:

$$4|(a+b+c)c-(a+c)(b+c)|\le(a+b+c)^2$$

i.e.

$$4ab\le (a+b+c)^2$$

(as $a,b\ge 0$), which is true because $4ab\le (a+b)^2$ (AM/GM inequality, or notice that it is equivalent to $(a-b)^2\ge 0$) and $(a+b)^2\le (a+b+c)^2$ as $a,b,c\ge 0$.

The motivation for this proof comes from looking at a Venn diagram for sets $A$ and $B$ and breaking down the sets $A,B,A\cup B$ as *disjoint* unions of $A\setminus B,A\cap B,B\setminus A$.

Comment: omg thank you very much!!